# What is the recommended minimum number of Sifrei Torah that a shul should have?

Tags: synagogue, torah-service

My shul has about a dozen Sifrei Torah but only 3 are kosher. I feel that a shul needs a minimum of 4. My reasoning:

Next week is a good example - There are 2 days of Shavu'ot followed closely by Shabbat. I need 3 for Shavu'ot alone - the reading for the 1st day and 2nd days and the 3rd is for maftir. This means that one of the 3 is the Torah I will be using this coming Shabbat (Nasso), and when next Shabbat comes, I have to spend time rolling that Torah. (I don't have time to roll it on Friday morning, BTW.)

My shul doesn't see the need to repair another one. (It's not the cost - they can handle the repair cost.) I'm trying to convince the shul that without the 4th there is "tircha d'tzibur" several times per year when we have such situations.

Prior to making my case, I'd like some advice or, perhaps halachic backup to my main claim that a 4th Torah is necessary to avoid tircha d'tzibbur. Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if you have, what did you do?

Comment: I'm more worried that having all of those non-kosher sifrei Torah could lead to an issue of *lifnei iver*, or something else like that.

Comment: @Scimonster - Not a concern in my shul. The non-kosher ones are in the back row and the gartel is outside each of them, so it's clear that they're unusable.

Comment: Sounds more like a tircha d'gabbai issue ;-). But seriously, your argument is that they don't have someone to prepare the Torah between days. They can deal with that however they find appropriate for the person. A shul needs 3 to run an uninterrupted Shabbos service all potential days of the year (except for a shul that reads the Nassi from the Sefer Torah after davening - they could use 4).

Comment: @Yishai - Sounds more like a tircha d'gabbai issue ;-). - Actually, it's tircha d'Ba'al Kri'ah - It sems that I'm the only person in the shul that can locate where to roll things to. It's tircha d'tzibbur because G-d forbid they should have to wait an extra few minutes to eat their herring & kugel ;-&

Comment: @DanF The Torah's should all be rolled to the correct spots before prayers start because of Tircha deTzibbura.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Yes, I know this. That was stated in my question detail. Problem is that I am the only one in the shul that knows how to find the place, and I can't roll it in time. That's why the 4th Torah, I think, is needed.

Comment: @DanF That sounds like a very localized concern relating to your shul, not one that is of general interest.

Comment: @DanF In my shul we pretty much have one active sefer Torah we use. We roll it either Friday night or before Shacharis to prevent *tircha de'tzibburah*. There is no halachic need to have multiple sifrei Torah. In SA the most needed for one day is 3 (Shabbos, Rosh Chodesh Chanukah) and this is not a requirement...you can use one and roll it. (We roll very quickly by having the people who roll lift the Torah slightly (1-2 inches) above the bimah and roll mid-air. It goes really fast but you need strong wrists)

Comment: I don't recall seeing any related halachot, except that one is not allowed to roll a Sefer Torah in public (i.e. during services) which makes a good argument to have 3. What you need is a Sefer-Gabbai who has the responsibility to roll the Sefer before services. (That's been my job for over 2 decades.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Appreciate the suggestion. I am the shul's Ba'al Koriah as well as Sefer Gabbai, as well as other related Torah duties. My shul consists of very few members who read Hebrew well. Even those that can, can't recognize Torah script. And those that do, have no clue where most parshiot start. Hence, the main motive for my question. I would love a helper, but, alas, it won't happen. BTW, your stating "not allowed" is not true. It's suggested not to do that b/c of Torach Tzibbur. But, obviously, when you need to roll, you do it.